# How do I check min app version for iOS Universal Links?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm adding a new path for a universal link to my iOS app.

Is there any way to specify a min-app-version in apple-app-site-association for some paths (but not all)?

This is the situation I want to avoid:

- App already support some paths for universal links, but I want to add another
- Add native code for handling a new universal link path (something like path="/artist/*"), ship to app store
- Add the new path to apple-app-site-association
- **Problem:** someone who hasn't upgraded our app to latest version clicks link. apple-app-site-association tells it to open the app, but their version of app can't handle this new path, causing UI to fail.

Comment: Using another universal link or firebase dynamic links could be an option for you? In this way lagacy app reponds to the old univ link and new one use firebase dynamic link in order to manage the new part. Moreover firebase dynamic links give you the ability to send users to app store if they doesn't have your app and get some data from firebase during once the app as been installed.

Comment: @shadowsheep Short answer no. Long answer: tons of these links already exist in the wild. We just want to start handling them natively in our app if installed, instead of on web. Good thought though!

Comment: Based on my experience, I guess that nowadays there's no way to specify the min-app version in your AASA file, and if you don't use another link you won't be able to get rid of this scenario. But let's see if someone could show us a way that does not turn to be a "private API" (said that just for fun ^^)